# "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" error in Joomla 3.7.0 (html.php)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I recently updated my Joomla website to 3.7.0. and my contact form is not working properly; it is forever on "sending" status and never becomes "sent".

I do not think there is a problem with the module, but I believe the problematic code below is an issue, because it still persists after deactivating the module.

```
{
    $options['relative']      = isset($options['relative']) ? $options['relative'] : false;
    $options['pathOnly']      = isset($options['pathOnly']) ? $options['pathOnly'] : false;
    $options['detectBrowser'] = isset($options['detectBrowser']) ? $options['detectBrowser'] : true;
    $options['detectDebug']   = isset($options['detectDebug']) ? $options['detectDebug'] : true;
}
```

I am getting the error `"Cannot use a scalar value as an array"` in `html.php`.

Please help; this is my first StackOverflow post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - cannot use a scalar as an array warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019853/php-cannot-use-a-scalar-as-an-array-warning)

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring the variable $options, as an array, before using it.

```
$options = array();
```

Hope this will solve your issue. You can also check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019853/php-cannot-use-a-scalar-as-an-array-warning), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685138/cannot-use-a-scalar-value-as-an-array)

Thanks & Regards,
Kaif